# Two column should be formatted

Tags: html, css

I create footer like following but, seems not good. I want "Telephone" exactly below "Email" and it's content should also start from place.

I want my text in center. I don't mind if id or class need to given or need to change html little bit.

like:

```
               Name Surname                      Email:      namesurname@gmail.com
      Address: City, country                     Telephone:  +1 223 233 111
```

My Code

```css
#footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

#footer > div:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

#footer > div {
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer span {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span>Fname Lname</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Address:</span>
                    <span>City, Country</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span>Email:</span>
                    <span>namesurname@gmail.com</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Telephone:</span>
                    <span>+1 525 111 222</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a table layout:

```css
#footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* To replace the border */
  background:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) center/1px 60% no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding:20px 0;
}

#footer>div {
  display: table;
  margin:40px auto; /* Center  */
}

#footer>div>div {
  display: table-row;
}

#footer>div>div>span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding:0 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
}

/*Add empty cell for the Fnam Lname*/
#footer>div:first-child > div:first-child:before {
  content:"";
  display:table-cell;
}
/**/
```

```html
<section id="footer">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Fname Lname</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Address:</span>
      <span>City, Country</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Email:</span>
      <span>namesurname@gmail.com</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Telephone:</span>
      <span>+1 525 111 222</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: But, it changed text align to left. I want text to be center.

Comment: @ketan check the update again, changed all the code and it's now centred

Answer (score 1):

One possiblility without changing the HTML is to apply `display: inline-block;` and `text-align: left;` to all spans, and then apply different (percentage or pixel) widths to the first and last children spans in the second DIV as shown below:

(text-alignment will only affect the spans with a defined width.)

```css
#footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#footer>div:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

#footer>div {
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer span {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

#footer>div:last-child>div>span:first-child {
  width: 20%;
}

#footer>div:last-child>div>span:last-child {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Fname Lname</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Address:</span>
      <span>City, Country</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Email:</span>
      <span>namesurname@gmail.com</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Telephone:</span>
      <span>+1 525 111 222</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your HTML, you can simply set `text-align: left` on the containing `<div>`. As you have no classes or IDs, this is easiest targeted with `#footer > div:nth-of-type(2) > div`.

Note that this will push your text flush up against the central divide, so you'll probably also want some `margin-left` or `padding-left`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
#footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

#footer > div:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

#footer > div {
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer span {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: white;
}

#footer > div:nth-of-type(2) > div {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Fname Lname</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Address:</span>
      <span>City, Country</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Email:</span>
      <span>namesurname@gmail.com</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Telephone:</span>
      <span>+1 525 111 222</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: But, i want text in center. I want mind giving id or class.